# Salvar variável em JavaScript e passar na URL do getjSon

Tags: javascript, json

Bom pessoal sou novo no JavaScript, e preciso salvar o valor do campo matricula em uma variável e passar ela na URL de um getJson. como posso fazer isso? segue o código abaixo das duas funções:
Código para salvar a variavel de matricula:

```
$(function($){
    $('#btn_entrar').click(function(){
        var matricula = $('#id_matricula').val();
    });
);
```

Código para chamar meu getJson:

```
$("#btn_entrar").click(function(event){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("URL/'ValorDaVariavelMatricula'", function(data){
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: Porque você tem dois eventos *click* para o mesmo botão `#btn_entrar`? Tem que *juntar* os dois.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que você está criando dois eventos para o mesmo botão `#brn_entrar`. Basta juntar os códigos. Você pega o valor do campo e coloca na variável `matricula`, depois chama o `getJSON` concatenando essa variável à string url:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn_entrar').on("click", function() {
        var matricula = $('#id_matricula').val();

        $.getJSON("URL/" + matricula, function(data){
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá, amigo, acho que a melhor solução seria usar `ajax`, segue abaixo o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_entrar').click(function(){
        var matricula = $('#id_matricula').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {matricula: matricula},
            success: function(json){
                // aqui trata seu json
            },
            error: function(json){
                alert('erro');
            }
        });     
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: [`$.getJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) é um atalho para [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) como descrito na documentação.